# Instruction pipelining - how is store/load behaving?

Tags: assembly, pipeline, cpu-architecture

So, if I have a pipeline with Fetch, Decode, Execute, Memory Access and Write Back, how does the store/load function work? For example if I have sw $1,$2 (store a word from $2 to $1) will it do something at WB or will store the value at MEM directly And do nothing at WB? If someone could explain to me the instruction above at every stage in pipeline would be great

Comment: Yes, WB is for updating the register file. Since `sw` does not update a register, nothing happens in that step.

Comment: A five stage pipeline was relevant 34 years ago, the "classic risc pipeline".  Relevant only to teaching, good to think about how you'd make a processor more efficient.  But has very little to do with how microprocessors work today, so can be very misleading.  Do talk to your professor about it, something like "but how do they do it now?" might help to get them to talk about what you really need to know.

Comment: The important issue in a pipeline is that a hardware resource must be associated to a stage. For instance, ALU is associated to stage "execute" and only to this stage. Otherwise, some instruction sequences could lead to conflicts if different instructions need the same resource. For this reason, memory is associated to stage "memory access"  and either reads or writes to memory are done at this stage. So for `sw`, write to memory is done at stage 4 and nothing has to be done at stage "write back".